# Why doesn't the buttons align up properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, pypy

So, I have been trying to design a simple calculator `GUI` using `Tkinter`. But I am facing this weird issue that I can't fix. This is my code, I hope it doesn't look messy.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

display = Entry(root,width=48,borderwidth=5)
display.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1",width=16,height=3)
button_2 = Button(root, text="2",width=16,height=3)
button_3 = Button(root, text="3",width=16,height=3)
button_4 = Button(root, text="4",width=16,height=3)
button_5 = Button(root, text="5",width=16,height=3)
button_6 = Button(root, text="6",width=16,height=3)
button_7 = Button(root, text="7",width=16,height=3)
button_8 = Button(root, text="8",width=16,height=3)
button_9 = Button(root, text="9",width=16,height=3)
button_0 = Button(root, text="0",width=16,height=3)

button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear",width=32,height=3)
button_plus = Button(root, text="+",width=16,height=3)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=",width=32,height=3)

button_1.grid(row=3,column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3,column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2,column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2,column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1,column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4,column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2)
button_plus.grid(row=5,column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5,column=1,columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of the GUI[image]

`First Problem`: Why doesn't the `clear` and `equal` button align up with the `3`, `6`, `9` buttons, just look at the `right margin` of the buttons, how its not properly aligned.

I have set the width for buttons 3, 6, 9 as `16` and for `clear` and `equal` buttons its just double `32`, and also these clear and equal buttons have `column-span` of `2` columns.

`Second Problem`: This is a secondary issue since it doesn't make the GUI look ugly. Why does't the `entry widget` on the top match the `width` of the `number buttons` below it, the entry widget's width is set to `48`, `thrice` the individual buttons.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: @БогданОпир I'll keep that in mind the next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the button is literally too small to take up 2 columns, and `tkinter` doesn't stretch them up automatically. You'd have to configure the stretching manually using `sticky` property so it knows the direction(s) of the stretch: `button_clear.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2, sticky='we')`. Here is your full code fixed:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

display = Entry(root,width=48,borderwidth=5)
display.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1",width=16,height=3)
button_2 = Button(root, text="2",width=16,height=3)
button_3 = Button(root, text="3",width=16,height=3)
button_4 = Button(root, text="4",width=16,height=3)
button_5 = Button(root, text="5",width=16,height=3)
button_6 = Button(root, text="6",width=16,height=3)
button_7 = Button(root, text="7",width=16,height=3)
button_8 = Button(root, text="8",width=16,height=3)
button_9 = Button(root, text="9",width=16,height=3)
button_0 = Button(root, text="0",width=16,height=3)

button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear",width=32,height=3)
button_plus = Button(root, text="+",width=16,height=3)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=",width=32,height=3)

button_1.grid(row=3,column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3,column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2,column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2,column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1,column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4,column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2, sticky='we')
button_plus.grid(row=5,column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5,column=1,columnspan=2, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I have made some changes according to above and also made it look-good.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

display = Entry(root,width=33,borderwidth=5, font = ('Helvetica',15, 'bold'))
display.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,  ipady =10)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_2 = Button(root, text="2",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_3 = Button(root, text="3",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_4 = Button(root, text="4",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_5 = Button(root, text="5",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_6 = Button(root, text="6",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_7 = Button(root, text="7",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_8 = Button(root, text="8",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_9 = Button(root, text="9",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_0 = Button(root, text="0",width=16,height=3, bd =5)

button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear",width=32,height=3, bd =5)
button_plus = Button(root, text="+",width=16,height=3, bd =5)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=",width=32,height=3, bd =5)

button_1.grid(row=3,column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3,column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2,column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2,column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1,column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4,column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2, sticky = 'we')
button_plus.grid(row=5,column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5,column=1,columnspan=2, sticky = 'we')

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you please tell why have you made the width of the entry widget = 33 and not 32?

Comment: It is because if I will use `width= 32` then it will not suit the gui and make it look ugly. That's why I used `width = 33`.

Comment: Do you mind a upvote if you find my post satisfactory please .